# Why is keybase/gui_config.json owned by root?

Tags: linux, keybase

I have keybase running on my Linux Desktop (Ubuntu 19.04). Since a recent update, the file `~/.config/keybase/gui_config.json` is owned by root which is quite irritating. One negative effect of this is that I cannot add the file to my backup. All the file contains is

```
{
    "gui": true
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a valid reason for this? Is this a bug and I can simply `chown` this? I don't want to mess up my keybase.

Comment: If that's all the gui_config.json holds, does it really need to be backed up?

Comment: I backup my whole `.config` and it feels stupid to exclude that one file. Also I have no idea whether the nice people from the keybase project will put more into that file in the future. So yes, I'd like to have it in my backup.

Comment: And also the question remains: Why is a file in my personal config folder owned by root?

Comment: Create a support ticket or perhaps they have a forum where this question can be asked. Or change the ownership permissions yourself (if possible). It doesn't make sense that files located ~/.config are owned by root (perhaps an installation bug)